# How Get value of JS promptbox then save into Array

Tags: javascript

```
                      var sav =new Array();
                       sav[] =prompt("Enter value");
                           while(a!="x")
                             {
                     var a =prompt("Enter value");
                             sav[a]=a;
                              }
                            if(a==x)
                            document.write(sav[a]);
```

How Get value of JS promptbox then save into Array
 help...!

Comment: `var x = prompt("enter number"); sav.push(x)`

Comment: `sav[] = x` is not valid JavaScript syntax. I believe you're looking for `sav.push(x)`. However, from this code, it's difficult to guess what you're actually trying to accomplish. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pjr5cmh/2/) for an example of how to do this with a function so you can reuse the code multiple times.

Here's the code:

```
var responses = [];

var askAUser = function() {
    var userText = prompt("Enter text:");
    responses.push(userText);
    return responses;
};

// Ask by invoking function
askAUser();

// Shows that the user info has been added to the array.
console.log(responses);
```

Comment: No problem Danish Khan! Don't forget to pick an answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function to add the retrieved value to the array.

`sav.push( prompt("Enter value"));`

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uz5s2vpL/

If you want to use the value elsewhere within the code, store it within a variable.

```
  var sav = [];
  var result = prompt("Enter value"));
  sav.push(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin But Saving Values in array not Display